# PHP session variable not persisting through AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I wanted to use HTML links to change a session variable in PHP.  To do this, I set up an HTML "a" tag that would call a javascript function that looks like this:

```
function changeValue(name){
  data = "key='person'&value=" + _name;
  $.ajax({
      url: www_root + "/funcs.php?func=set_session_var",
      type: "post",
      data: data,
      success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
      }
  }); 
  }
```

Then, I had the funcs.php script which had the set_session_var function like this:

```
function set_session_var(){
   session_start();
   $key= trim($_GET["key"]);
   $value= trim($_GET["value"]);
   $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
   session_write_close();
   echo $key;
}
```

Then, the original php/html page would reload, but it would first load an external page (call it item.php) that settled all of the php session stuff.  Looks like this:

```
session_start()
$session_id = session_id();
$sc = $_SESSION['person'];
```

However, the $sc variable always shows up as empty, despite the AJAX success function returning the right value.  I've checked the session_id's for both scripts, and they are the same.  I have also tried to set a session variable in item.php, and it persists.  It's just that when I set a session variable using the funcs.php script it doesn't save.

Any and all ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending quotes:

```
data = "key='person'&value=" + _name;
            ^------^
```

which means you're effectively doing:

```
$_SESSION["'person'"] = $value;
           ^------^-
```

Note that those single quotes have become PART of the session key name.

Try

```
data = "key=person&value=" + _name;
            ^----^--- no quotes
```

instead.

Comment: Worked beautifully.  Thanks